# Unity app not running on Cyanogen OS 12

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, cyanogenmod

I installed the Treasure Hunt app on my phone with the help of the Google Cardboard SDK for Unity. The app shows the splash screen and stops immediately.
The phone runs on Cyanogen OS 12. This app seems to run on MIUI with Android 4.4 KitKat. Can anyone tell me the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've run into issues with Unity games on Cyanogenmod. I think it has to do with the OpenGL library that Cyanogen packages with its ROM/OS. It's on the developer to fix it AFAIK.

Comment: This is not a programming question, head over to android.stackexchange.com